# Should I observe a signal multiple times for MUSIC algorithm?

Tags: autocorrelation, music

In a paper [Multiple emitter location and signal parameter estimation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1143830/?arnumber=1143830), the well-known MUSIC algorithm starts by calculating covariance (autocorrelation, whatever) matrix with:

[image]

where overlines stand for expectation operation, i.e., $\overline{XX^H}\triangleq E\left[XX^H\right]$. As I understand, the MUSIC algorithm needs to observe signals multiple times to get $S$, i.e., $S=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^{N}{X_{i}X_{i}^{H}}$

On the other hand, when I googled implementations of the MUSIC algorithm, most of them does not perform expectation operation. I mean, they just observe signals only one time and perform the remaining process of the algorithm, i.e., $S=XX^H$

Is there a reasonable explanation that the MUSIC algorithm does not need to observe signals multiple times, but only need to observe signals only once?

Comment: Self answer: http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A724272&dswid=-9347 claims that sample autocorrelation (what I've said in the original question) needs to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very much related to [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34721/80).

The issue is that the expectation operator to get the auto-correlation (auto-covariance) is generally replaced in signal processing with the sample auto-correlation.